# CSS / jQuery - How to make a div, that is not placed at the top of the page, to be at the top of the page while page is been scrolled down

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the next issue -

The next code shows 3 divs - the first is a big red box, which sits at the top of the page, and underneath it there is a blue box. The last div shows 'info'.

Now what I would like to do is to make the blue box scrolled down but also that it will be at the top of the page when the red box is out of sight, and when the red box is view-able then the blue box will be at the bottom of it.

Also another thing I would like to take care of is the possibility that the height of the red box can be a different value when, let's say the page is being re-sized.

So this is the simple code -

```
        <script>



        $(document).ready(function () {


            var totaltext = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                totaltext += "scroll!<br />";
            }
            $("#div2").html(totaltext);



        });
    </script>

    <style>
        .top_box {
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: red;
            //position: absolute;
        }

        .scrolling_box {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: blue;
            position: fixed;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="top_box"></div>
    <div class="scrolling_box"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>

</body>
```

Any idea how can I do it?
Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: Like this? http://codepen.io/senff/pen/ayGvD

Comment: Yeah - thanks for your help - and sorry for not seeing this before- cheers